# Rate limit of the Rest api using spring cloud gateway does not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, java-11, spring-cloud-gateway

I tried to run, but I don’t understand that why don’t show an error when to occur rate limit to rest api.

GatewaySecureRateLimiterTest - I only observe the success of requests, but I do not see errors when limiting requests.

In addition, I would like to clarify for myself (I did not find it in the documentation):

I would like to clarify for myself (I didn't find this in the documentation):

- how to change the error code to the address to which the response was sent that the resource is currently busy
- is it possible to collect statistics and see which IP generates more requests than our endpoint can handle
- the speed limit can only be configured using *. yml, or it can also be configured using Java, while ?
- I would like to see it in tests. what is the restriction-it triggers and gets detailed information(for example, from which IP and how many requests and in what unit of time).
- I also didn't fully understand what the meaning of these parameters is:

  - key determinant: "#{@userRemoteAddressResolver}"
  - reuse rate limiter.Top-up rate: 1
  - reuse rate limiter.Bandwidth: 1

For example, I would like to know what is the number of requests in these parameters, and what is the unit of time during which this number of requests should work ?

```yaml
server:
  port: ${PORT:8085}

logging.pattern.console: "%clr(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}){blue} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){yellow} %clr(:){red} %clr(%m){faint}%n"

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  redis:
    host: 192.168.99.100
    port: 6379
  output.ansi.enabled: ALWAYS
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: account-service
        uri: http://localhost:8085
        predicates:
        - Path=/account/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/account/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
        - name: RequestRateLimiter
          args:
              key-resolver: "#{@userKeyResolver}"
              redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 10
              redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 20
```

- config-security

```java
 @Configuration
//@ConditionalOnProperty("rateLimiter.secure")
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        http.authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                exchanges
                        .anyExchange()
                        .authenticated())
                .httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService users() {

        UserDetails user1 = User.builder()
                .username("user1")
                .password("{noop}1234")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails user2 = User.builder()
                .username("user2")
                .password("{noop}1234")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails user3 = User.builder()
                .username("user3")
                .password("{noop}1234")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user1, user2, user3);

    }

}
```

- config

```java
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConditionalOnProperty("rateLimiter.non-secure")
    KeyResolver userKeyResolver() {
        return exchange -> Mono.just("1");
    }

   // @Bean
   // @ConditionalOnProperty("rateLimiter.secure")
    KeyResolver authUserKeyResolver() {

        return exchange -> ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(securityContext -> securityContext.getAuthentication()
                        .getPrincipal()
                        .toString()
                );
    }
}
```

- test

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
                properties = {"rateLimiter.non-secure=true"})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class GatewayRateLimiterTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayRateLimiterTest.class);

    private Random random = new Random();

    @Rule
    public TestRule benchmarkRun = new BenchmarkRule();

    private static final DockerImageName IMAGE_NAME_MOCK_SERVER =
            DockerImageName.parse("jamesdbloom/mockserver:mockserver-5.11.2");

    @ClassRule
    public static MockServerContainer mockServer =
            new MockServerContainer(IMAGE_NAME_MOCK_SERVER);


    @ClassRule
    public static GenericContainer redis =
            new GenericContainer("redis:5.0.6")
                    .withExposedPorts(6379);

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;



    @Test
    @BenchmarkOptions(warmupRounds = 0, concurrency = 6, benchmarkRounds = 600)
    public void testAccountService() {

        String username = "user" + (random.nextInt(3) + 1);

        HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders(username,"1234");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<Account> responseEntity =
                testRestTemplate.exchange("/account/{id}",
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        entity,
                        Account.class,
                        1);



        LOGGER.info("Received: status->{}, payload->{}, remaining->{}",
                responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue(),
                responseEntity.getBody(),
                responseEntity.getHeaders()
                        .get("X-RateLimit-Remaining"));


    }

    private HttpHeaders createHttpHeaders(String user, String password) {

        String notEncoded = user + ":" + password;

        String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(notEncoded.getBytes());

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth);

        return headers;
    }

}
```

- repository

[here](https://github.com/alex-sky-cloud/spring-gateway.git)